# ssh echo command and result of its execution

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I would like to assign ssh output to variable like:

```
VAR="$(ssh $HOST "uname -a")"
```

VAR receives only result of command execution. 
Is it possible to get two lines command+result without calling additional echo?

Expected VAR value:

```
hostname>uname -a
E570 4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu
```

Comment: Sounds like an equivalent to `@echo on` on Windows.

Comment: `var=$(cmd='uname -a'; echo "$cmd"; ssh host "$cmd")`

Comment: @pynexj Original question said "without calling additional echo".

Comment: @pynexj yes it's clear solution. but I wonder if there is possibility to do it without additional commands. probably there is a ssh specific key to enable echo of command itself

Comment: what about `ssh host 'set -x; uname'`? or `ssh host $'set -v\nuname'`?

Comment: @shellter you are not right. it is possible to use dbl quotes inside subshell "$("")"

Comment: Well my comment doesn't answer your Q. I don't think it is possible to get the output you required without two commands (usually `echo "$Var"`) being executed. Good luck.

Comment: And I (re)learned something today, `var="$(echo "multi word     with extra spaces")"; echo "$var"` produces `multi word     with extra spaces`. (Hmm there are really extra spaces there ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: Hm.. how about  `var="$(echo "multi word     WITH extra spaces"|tee /dev/pty0)"` where `echo "..."` is my local place holder for your `ssh` cmd. (and again, there are extra spaces that the comments engine is deleting). I'm guessing you don't want any extra command, but your Q specifies `echo`. I don't know the `1>&4` sort of redirections, maybe that can duplicate output rather than just redirect it. Good luck.

Comment: @user947668 What you mean by $HOST?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
HOST=hostname
CMD="uname -a"
VAR="$HOST>$CMD #the new line is needed
$(ssh $HOST "$CMD")"
```

Now if you do:

```
echo "$VAR"
```

You obtain:

```
hostname>uname -a
E570 4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu
```

I think this is the only way to avoid using *echo* command, but you need to assign the command to execute in ssh into a variable.

Comment: You forgot the dollar sign in `"$CMD"`. Generally, putting commands in variables is a dubious idea. `ssh` needs to be lower case.

Comment: yes, sorry is a typing error! thank you i will correct it